# How to elevate a specific style error in cppcheck

Tags: c++, c++11, static-analysis, cppcheck

I use cppcheck via the CLI in a continuous integration test parcours. If cppcheck fails, my job fails. Thus, I am limiting the issues cppcheck tests in order to not halt the development completely.

More specifically, I currently use `--enable=missingInclude,warning` together with some `--suppress`.

How can I elevate specific, non-error and non-warning issue to let cppcheck fail, e.g. [`missingOverride`](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/commit/b830f462e6d18f62406ac11afbc7a39247d57122), which is of the category "style" ?

- `--enable=missingOverride` does not seem to work as enable only accepts `error|warning|style|performance|portability|information|all`
- `--enable=style` is also no option because then I have way too many aspects to take care of to get my CI running again instead of fixing them iteratively

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible in a simple way. What would work is to add the option `--enable=style` (it enables also other messages like performance!) and then specify a file with a list of suppressions via `--suppressions-list=`. In that file, you can add all error ids you do not want to get warnings for. Yes, this is not ideal and if you use a new Cppcheck version there could be new error ids that have to be added. But currently, there is no better way as far as I know. Maybe you want to discuss/suggest such a feature in the forum: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion

Comment: @versat Good idea, thanks. I opened a discussion here: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/development/thread/329240dfd2/